# Find the $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find the $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^{2}} $.

I have tried the L'Hospital rule. I seems that this doesn't work very well. I don't know what kind other approach we can attack this problem.

Comment: Substitute $t = 1/x$.

Comment: substitute and apply L'Hospital

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-\frac1x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x}=0$$and$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{-\frac1x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x}=+\infty.$$Therefore, your limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y: = 1/x$:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2} =$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{y^2}{e^y}=0$.

Note: $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{y^k}{e^y}= 0$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.